# Bxslider adaptiveHeigt pushes content

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am using 2 Bxsliders on my web page, and the first one has an adaptive height.
Now when a larger (or smaller) image appears, The next slider and/or content keeps their margin of 25 pixels to the changed height, So my content keeps moving out of position, Ive tried wrappers and stuff to give a top or a position absolute but neither worked, and i cant seem to find anyone else on google with this problem... I hope some of u can push me in the right direction as am fairly new

A big thnx so far

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slider_big').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 830,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
        auto: true,
        pause: 4000,
        controls: false,
        easing: 'swing',
        pager: false
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slider_small').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 200,
        minSlides: 4,
        maxSlides: 4,
        slideMargin: 10,
        pager: false
      });
    });
```

**html:**

```
 <body>
    <div id="main_wrapper">

        <div class="slider_big">
            <div class="slide"><img src="sliders/slide-images/big-slide/830-1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="sliders/slide-images/big-slide/830-2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="sliders/slide-images/big-slide/830-3.jpg"></div>
        </div> <!-- Sluiting slider_big -->

        <div class="slider_small">
            <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar1"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar2"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar3"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar4"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar5"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar6"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar7"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar8"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar9"></div>
        </div> <!-- Sluiting slider_small -->   
    </div> <!-- Sluiting wrapper -->
  </body>
```

Comment: If a the first bx slider has adaptive height and the slides have different proportions then everything else under it in the flow of the document will of course go up and down.  The only thing you could do is wrap the first slider in a fixed height div equal to the maximum slide height.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it, somethimes im thinking to difficult lol
Thnx for responding so quickly and clear.

Comment: Hey no probs - glad to help, welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Take the autoheight option off and declare a fixed height in CSS.

```
.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport, .bx-wrapper img {height: 400px !important;}
```

This way, bxslider height will be 400 pixels. Then you can play with the picture inside

to be centered.